# Protractor testing, Headless RH 6.5 and ChromeDriver GLIBCXX_3.4.15' issue

Tags: protractor, redhat, selenium-chromedriver, libstdc++

So I'm doing protractor testing on a redHat 6.5 server, and I'm having issues with  chromedriver, whenever I try to run it, its given me this error

```
./chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
```

I fixed this installing [chrome](http://www.tecmint.com/install-google-chrome-on-redhat-centos-fedora-linux/) and making a link to where the system libstdc library was found.

```
$ cd /usr/lib64/
$ ln -s /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

but after a while the link gets restored to its original version, I'm still not sure if its the system automatically restoring itself, or someone else.  Anyway I found another [solution](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=440), and what it does is make a copy of chrome and modify the last line from this :

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \
"$@"
```

to this:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chromedriver"  "$@"
```

so that it calls chromedriver instead and finally create a link to /usr/bin/chromedriver.
but nothing when I run chromdriver it just sits there and nothing
I've even try the last line like so:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chromedriver"  "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \
"$@"
```

Still no luck:

**Questions:**

1. Has anybody been able to fix this?
2. Is it normal behavior for RH to have libs restored in that way back to is defaults
3. Any Ideas why the chromedriver tweak might not be working apparently it worked before
4. is there any way to tell chromedriver where to find the libstdc++ manually like in a parameter or something like :

   ./chromedriver --libstdc=/opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to override the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that the system uses to find libraries when loading chromedriver.

Specifically, try:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/google/chrome/lib/ chromedriver
```

This should make the dynamic linker (ld-linux.so) look in the installed chrome library directory first when looking for libraries to match.  You can debug this by adding `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=yep` to the environment (see `man ld-linux.so` for more debugging variables you can set).

If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is already set to something in your environment, you may need to tweak things to pass that a long (e.g., `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/google/chrome/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`)

See https://superuser.com/questions/192573/how-do-you-specify-the-location-of-libraries-to-a-binary-linux

Comment: at a command level it does work, what I did was to call a small script that ultimately will call the chromedriver. and it does work, now since I'm calling this guy from a jenkins job somehow the driver just crashes, after finishing loading. So now I've rolled back to the symlink solution.   I know is ugly but for now it works,   I'll continue and try when I have a spare time to see how to fix the error, with your suggestion. Thanks for your time